# DES, RSA encryption and decryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, des

So I decided to enhance my python skills in encryption and decryption, and attempted to write a python program that executes the following:

- Generates a 1024 bit private key and public key
- Encrypt the private key with the DES algorithm
- Save the encrypted private key to a file
- Save the public key to a file
- Uses the public key to encrypt through the RSA algorithm, a file

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\python\E&D.py", line 10, in <module>
    pr = RSA.importKey(open('mykey.pem', 'r'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 678, in importKey
    if bord(externKey[0])==0x30:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

My code:

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

# Generate Private Key
private = RSA.generate(1024)
m = open('mykey.pem','w')
m.write(private.exportKey('PEM'))

#Get public key
public = private.publickey()
pr = RSA.importKey(open('mykey.pem', 'r'))

#DES encryption
password= '01234567'
des= DES.new(password,DES.MODE_ECB)
des_cipher= des.encrypt(pr)

f = open('privatekey.dat','w')
l = open('publickey.dat','w')
s=open('encrypted.dat','w')
w = open('encrypt.dat', 'r')
war = w.read()
f.write(des_cipher)
l.write(public)

#RSA encryption
enc_data = public.encrypt(war)
s.write(enc_data)
f.close()
l.close()
s.close()
w.close()
m.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`RSA.importKey()` takes a string, not a file. Read the file:

```
pr = RSA.importKey(open('mykey.pem', 'r').read())
```

or, using a context manager to close the file properly:

```
with open('mykey.pem', 'r') as keyfile:
    pr = RSA.importKey(keyfile.read())
```

Using the files as context managers removes the need to call `close` on each of them at the end.

From the [`RSA.importKey()` documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#importKey):

> `importKey(externKey, passphrase=None)`
>
> Import an RSA key (public or private half), encoded in standard form.
>
> [...]
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `externKey` (string) - The RSA key to import, encoded as a string.

Next, you can't encrypt the RSA private key object. You can only encrypt bytes, so export the private key again. You'll need to pad out the string (using the PKCS#7 standard, preferably) to a multiple of the block length:

```
plaintext = pr.exportKey('PEM')
remainder = len(plaintext) % des_cipher.block_length
if remainder:
    # add padding
    pad_length = des.block_length - remainder
    plaintext += chr(pad_length) * pad_length
des_cipher = des.encrypt(remainder)
```